# Docker: NestJS and MySQL ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: docker-compose, nestjs

I have this files:

docker-compose-yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_crud
      MYSQL_USER: user_crud
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-backend
    container_name: backend_service
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
```

Dockerfile-backend

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

app.module.ts

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3307,
  username: 'user_crud',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'db_crud',
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: true,
}),
```

I'm getting while running `docker compose up` this error:

```
backend_service | [Nest] 41  - 01/11/2024, 12:13:01 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
backend_service | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307
backend_service |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16)
```

Why?
I tried with 3307 and 3306 on `app.module.ts` having the same error (with different ports values in the error message).

Any idea?

Comment: The database is not running on `localhost`. It is running on a host named `mysql`, so you should use that as the value of the `host` parameter in your connection information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your docker-compose file, I think there are some place to fix.

try to add networks

[image]

To fix this I change a app.module.ts file.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'mysql',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'user_crud',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'db_crud',
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  synchronize: true,
}),
```

And got a result.
[image]

When you use docker-compose, network works differently.
container will use docker inner network.
In your docker-compose, mysql service was mysql(not container name). So I write a mysql at host. This will make docker to find local docker container.

You could check my git repository [link](https://github.com/Alex-Choi0/NestJS_Connect_mysql_docker-compose.git).

Good luck!